# Get values from json with linq

Tags: linq, json.net

I have this launchSettings.json in my app:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "ProfileA": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "-c",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "http://ayda.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/api",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "variableA" : "valueA",
        "variableB" : "valueB"
      }
    },
    "ProfileB": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "-c",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000/api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "variable1" : "value1",
        "variable2" : "value2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get all values from "environmentVariables" section from "profileB". For this I wrote some code using json.net:

```
using (var file = File.OpenText("Properties\\launchSettings.json"))
{
    var reader = new JsonTextReader(file);
    var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

    var variables = jObject.GetValue("profiles")["profileB"]["environmentVariables"].Children<JProperty>().ToList(); //how to do this in linq
    foreach (var variable in variables)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(variable.Name + " " + variable.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

It outputs

```
variable1 : value1
variable2 : value2
```

It does exactly what I want but **how to do the same thing with LINQ?**

I found this approach but it returns values from **all** "environmentVariables" sections of this file:

```
var variables = jObject
                    .GetValue("profiles")
                    .SelectMany(profiles => profiles.Children())
                    .SelectMany(profile => profile.Children<JProperty>())
                    .Where(prop => prop.Name == "environmentVariables")
                    .SelectMany(prop => prop.Value.Children<JProperty>())
                    .ToList();
```

It outputs

```
variableA : valueA
variableB : valueB
variable1 : value1
variable2 : value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
var variables = jObject.GetValue("profiles")["ProfileB"].Last
                            .SelectMany(profile => profile.Children<JProperty>())
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank for ansver, it work. But how to make this part `["ProfileB"].Last` linq too. Maybe `Select` and `Where` combination or something?